# How to compile and run custom kernel in Android12 for Pixel 6?

Tags: android, build, kernel, android-12

I tried to compile the Android 12 kernel， consult：https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels?hl=en

1. mkdir android-kernel && cd android-kernel
2. repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-gs-raviole-5.10-android12L
3. repo sync
4. build/build.sh

I could see the logs below after I build successfully.
then：
fastboot flash boot boot.img

But I get immediately redirected back to the bootloader;
I unpack boot.img(Custom compilation) find boot.img contain ramdisk；
Do not know what causes, you have encountered? Hope to get your help

Comment: You weren't supposed to flash the boot image.  But rather the kernel itself, which is a Image-dtb.gz file.  I would suggest re-reading the instructions on that page